# Report Script formatting in essbase

Tags: report, essbase

Iam in the process of creating a report script from ASO cube. I am able to get the necessary contents on the report and finding it difficult to get in the required format.

```
//ESS_LOCALE English_UnitedStates.Latin1@Binary
<PAGE(Scenario)

<COLUMN(Accounts)

<ROW ( Entity, "Financial Years")
{ RENAME "01/01/2015" } "Jan 2015"
{ RENAME "02/01/2015" } "Feb 2015"
{ RENAME "03/01/2015" } "Mar 2015"
{ RENAME "04/01/2015" } "Apr 2015"
{ RENAME "05/01/2015" } "May 2015"
{ RENAME "06/01/2015" } "Jun 2015"
{ RENAME "07/01/2015" } "Jul 2015"
{ RENAME "08/01/2015" } "Aug 2015"
{ RENAME "09/01/2015" } "Sep 2015"
{ RENAME "10/01/2015" } "Oct 2015"
{ RENAME "11/01/2015" } "Nov 2015"
{ RENAME "12/01/2015" } "Dec 2015"
<DESCENDANTS 2015
<DESCENDANTS Entity

{ DECIMAL 1
SUPCOMMAS
SUPMISSINGROWS 
OUTMBRNAMES
TABDELIMIT 
ROWREPEAT}

Actual
     EBITDA "Salaries and wages"

 !
```

Current Output

```
Actual  Segment View    Historical Managerial   Company 
        EBITDA  Salaries and wages
      999   01/01/2015  11404.5 #Missing
      999   02/01/2015  14139.3 #Missing
      999   03/01/2015  159744.2    #Missing
      999   04/01/2015  54642.9 #Missing
```

Requirement is to remove unwanted headings and retain EBITDA and Salaries and Wages. Also want to add heading Entity above 999 column

Answer (score 0):

You can supress the heading with an option at the beginning of the report script.

```
{SUPPAGEHEADING}
```